# Using regex with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

One of my homework questions is to search using grep an lines that contain the word 'death' or 'breath'.

I know the [] operator acts as an or, but how do I use it to specify 'd' or 'br' ?

This won't work:

```
egrep [dbr]eath test_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep '(d|br)eath' test_file`

Answer (score 2):

`(d|br)` is for either `d or br`.

The square brackets are for matching a single character from square brackets.

For example: `[asdf]ello` would match aello, sello, dello, or fello.

Answer (score 1):

The "|" operator (vertical bar) acts as an "or". However:

```
grep 'breath|death' test_file
```

What you wrote would find "death", "beath", and "reath".

Answer (score 0):

Study up on "alternation" and you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

egrep is FYI, deprecated. Use `grep -E`

```
grep -E '(d|br)eath' file
```